# Using Ruby or Bash in the iPython Notebook without having to run the magic command in each cell

Tags: python, ruby, bash, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I want to execute Ruby or Bash in a cell, I just have to run commands like this:

```
%%ruby
%%bash
```

However, this only lasts until the end of the cell. Is there a function I can run in iPython that will automatically run this command in each cell I use unless I disable it?

Comment: If you want to write entire notebooks in bash, ruby or many other languages, you can install [kernels for those languages](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages).

Comment: True, I've seen experimental kernels for R as well, I'm just interested in executing the command by default in cells until I switch it off and am rather curious as to whether there is such an option :)

Comment: There's nothing in IPython that does stateful switching like that. You *could* code something up as an extension to do it, but I wouldn't recommend it.